# Why does this regular expression match with extra fields?

Tags: c#, regex, expression, match

First time poster, long time user.  I CAN NOT figure out why this data with this regular expression is passing when it should fail.  The quick overview is that I have a text file with pipe delimited data in it.  I'm reading each line in one at a time and comparing against a regex for pass/fail.

Here is the data in question:

```
|A|00032004|00032004|25 S Kings Highway||Cape Giradeau|MO|63701|345800886888|0000254575|091091|RGT Foods, Inc.|1|345800886888|1|345800886888|1|601103061404806|1|003241699917|0|000000000000|0|000000000000|0|000000000000|0|000000000000|
|A|00032005|00032005|1009 Kings Hwy||Rolla |MO|65401|345800885880|0000254564||RGT Foods, Inc.|1|345800885880|1|345800885880|1|601103061404798|1|003241699925|0|000000000000|0|000000000000|0|000000000000|0|000000000000|
```

Here's the basic breakdown:
|D,U,or A|ID#|ID#|St Add1|St Add2|City|ST|Zip|#|#|Name|bool|#|bool|#|bool|#|bool|#|bool|#|bool|#|bool|#|bool|#|

This is my regular expression (warning: it's kinda long):

```
^[\|]{1}[DUA]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9,A-Z]{8}[\|]{1}[0-9,A-Z]{8}[\|]{1}.{0,25}[\|]{1}.{0,25}[\|]{1}.{0,25}[\|]{1}[A-Z,a-z]{2}[\|]{1}[0-9]{5}[\|]{1}[A-Z,a-z,0-9]{12}[\|]{1}[A-Z,a-z,0-9]{10}[\|]{1}.{0,25}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{12}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{12}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{15}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{12}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{12}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{12}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{12}[\|]{1}[0,1]{1}[\|]{1}[0-9]{12}[\|]{1}
```

This is my regex function:

```
//Compare the entire line at once
public static bool MatchCCRegEx(string spLine)
{
    try
    {
        Regex CCLineCheck = new Regex(
                Properties.Settings.Default.CCRegExValidationString);
        Match CCLineMatch = CCLineCheck.Match(spLine);

        if (CCLineMatch.Success)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception RegExCheckExc)
    {
        WELogger.LogEvent("3", 
            "Error running RegEx check on this line:\r\n" 
            + spLine + "\r\n" + RegExCheckExc.ToString());

        Environment.Exit(9);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The example data I gave should fail because there is an extra field between # and Name with a value of 091091.  The second line should also fail because of the extra field (but it's empty on that one).  I've stared at the regex for hours, because it looks like to me at the "#|#|Name|bool", 091091 would've been put in for name and pass, but "RGT Foods, Inc." shouldn't pass as a 0 or 1...but both lines pass regex, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: a `[0-9,A-Z]` matches a letter, digit **or comma**. I guess you want `[0-9A-Z]`.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? I would use a delimited file parser.

Comment: whats wrong with [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split)?

Comment: To be honest, I would recommend looking up a good regex tutorial (http://www.regular-expressions.info is very informative). I get the feeling that many portions of your regex are not doing what you think they are. For example, what are you expecting to match with `[A-Z,a-z,0-9]` (I don't think it's what you're intending)? Why are you using `{1}` all over the place?

Comment: you need to regex your regex expression. Just as well the editor supported only 132 chars wide :-) Classic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a match because `.{0,25}` not only matches the `RGT Foods, Inc.` but also the `091091|` before it.

If you know your "free" fields won't contain any pipes, replace `.{0,25}` with `[^|]{0,25}`. ("Zero to 25 not-a-pipe characters".)

Also, for readability, note

- `[\|]` can be written `[|]` or `\|`.
- `{1}` can be removed completely; the default is "match once".
- `[A-Z,a-z,0-9]` matches A-Z, a-z, 0-9 *and commas*. You probably mean `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Similarly `[0,1]` should be `[01]` and `[0-9,A-Z]` should be `[0-9A-Z]`.

Honestly, though, if you know your free fields can't contain a pipe, I'd just `String.Split` on the pipe and validate each field separately. That regex is a nightmare.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I hate this regex, I'd like to clean it up.    I'm already calling a String.Split after I validate the line with RegEx, maybe I'll do a combo of both so I validate I have the correct number of pipes (fields) per line, then validate each field with a regex.  I'll definitely exclude the pipe from the "free" field, I didn't realize that's what it was doing!  I also didn't catch the third bullet either, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're allowing `|` as part of the match between delimiters. You probably don't want to do that. Also, you can cut down on a lot of surplus braces because `{1}` is unnecessary. You probably don't want to allow commas either:

```
^\|[DUA]\|[0-9A-Z]{8}\|[0-9A-Z]{8}\|[^|]{0,25}\|[^|]{0,25}\|[^|]{0,25}\|[A-Za-z]{2}\|[0-9]{5}\|[A-Za-z0-9]{12}\|[A-Za-z0-9]{10}\|[^|]{0,25}\|[01]\|[0-9]{12}\|[01]\|[0-9]{12}\|[01]\|[0-9]{15}\|[01]\|[0-9]{12}\|[01]\|[0-9]{12}\|[01]\|[0-9]{12}\|[01]\|[0-9]{12}\|[01]\|[0-9]{12}\|
```

Answer (score 0):

A `.{0,25}` matches anything (of length 0-25), *including* `|`. Try a `[^\|]{0,25}` to exclude `|`s.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex to parse a delimited file I suggest using a library that is built for this task.

A popular option is [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) and the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` has the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class that is made for this.